# Kotlin optional generic parameter

Tags: kotlin

Here is the problem I am trying to resolve, I am trying to use a void type as a generic type:

```
class Parent {
    private abstract class Item<out T>(val data: T)
    // This subclass should contain data
    private class ItemContent(val data: String): Item<String>(data)
    // This subclass doesn't contain data
    private class ItemNoContent: Item<Any?>(null)
}
```

Some base classes like ItemNoContent doesn't contain meaningful data so I make ItemNoContent extends Item(null). It works but I feel that the use of Any? and null is inappropriate here. Is there a more Kotlin way to solve this optional generic problem?

Comment: Does `Nothing` do what you want? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild it doesn't work since you can't assign `Nothing` to the `data` field.

Comment: @Pawel but you could use `Nothing?` and assign `null` to `data`. But I think the semantics are wrong? I'm not clear on when you'd want to use `Nothing?`. `Unit` makes more sense here.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can also use `Item<Unit>(Unit)` which represents a `void` value in Kotlin.

Answer (score 5):

> Some base classes like ItemNoContent doesn't contain meaningful data

Then why extend a class which is supposed to have it? While `Unit` and `null` are both options, consider also

```
private abstract class Item<out T>
private abstract class ItemWithContent<out T>(val data: T) : Item<T>
...
// object may make more sense than class here
private object ItemNoContent : Item<Nothing>()
```

Answer (score 5):

I would tweak the inheritance like this:

```
abstract class Item

abstract class ItemWithContent<T>(val d: T): Item()

class ItemWithStringContent(d: String): ItemWithContent<String>(d)

class ItemWithNoContent: Item()
```

This way, there is not need to use `Unit` or `Nothing`.

Usage:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val t: Item = ItemWithStringContent("test")
    println((t as? ItemWithStringContent)?.d)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but there is a more elegant way to do this now using `data object` and algebraic data types.

```kotlin
sealed interface Item

data class ItemContent<T : Any>(val content: T) : Item

data object ItemNoContent : Item
```

There are a couple of different variations on how you can implement this exactly. For example, `ItemContent` could be implemented as a value class. Or you can pull the generic type up to `Item<T>` and have `ItemNoContent : Item<Nothing>`

But in any implementation, this hierarchy is very similar to what an [`Option`](https://apidocs.arrow-kt.io/arrow-core/arrow.core/-option/index.html) is.